# Extract specific currency amount from string in Python

Tags: python, regex

I would like to extract prices with currencies (list) that have this form:

- $ 1.10
- € 1,10
- 1,10 €
- $ 1
- € 18
- 1€
- 5$
- $1.10
- €1,10
- 1,10€
- 1.99$
- 1,99$
- Eur 1.10
- Eur 1,99
- Eur 10
- Eur1.10
- Eur1,99
- Eur10
- 1.10 dollar
- 1,99 dollar
- 10 dollar

I tryed this python function re.findall(pattern, string)
with regex

`(?:[\£\$\€]{1}[,\d]+.?\d*)`

https://regex101.com/r/X5SPDK/1

but I don't get the expected result

Comment: Um, you didn't even try, dude: for example, your regex doesn't even attempt to match `dollar`, `Eur` or the currency sign being to the right of the actual value. The same about the space between the currency sign and the value. Also, `.` doesn't match the literal dot _exclusively_, it'll also match `ü`, for example.

Comment: When you say this form, do you mean the literals in that list ? That is just `^(?:\$(?:[ ]1(?:\.10)?|1\.10)|1(?:,(?:10[ ]?€|99(?:[ ]dollar|\$))|\.(?:10[ ]dollar|99\$)|0[ ]dollar|€)|5\$|Eur[ ]?1(?:,99|\.10|0)|€(?:[ ]1(?:,10|8)|1,10))$`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are not validating, this expression might be a bit closer to what you might have in mind:

```
[£$€]\s*[.,\d]+|[.,\d]+\s*[£$€]|(?:Eur|dollars?)\s*[.,\d]+|[.,\d]+\s*(?:Eur|dollars?)
```

and it would fail for validations. You can also add capturing groups if you might want to capture the numbers.

#### Test

```
import re

regex = r"[£$€]\s*[.,\d]+|[.,\d]+\s*[£$€]|(?:Eur|dollars?)\s*[.,\d]+|[.,\d]+\s*(?:Eur|dollars?)"

test_str ="""
I bought a car $12,250,000 it was expensive 
that thing was £14,500,123.125521 dollas 
afsaf£120.25sfsafsa 
$ 1.10
€ 1,10
1,10 €

$ 1

€ 18
1€
5$

$1.10

€1,10
1,10€
1.99$
1,99$

Eur 1.10

Eur 1,99
Eur 10

Eur1.10

Eur1,99
Eur10

1.10 dollar

1,99 dollar
10 dollar


"""

print(re.findall(regex, test_str, re.I))
```

---

#### Output

```
['$12,250,000', '£14,500,123.125521', '£120.25', '$ 1.10', '€ 1,10', '1,10 €', '$ 1', '€ 18', '1€', '5$', '$1.10', '€1,10', '1,10€', '1.99$', '1,99$', 'Eur 1.10', 'Eur 1,99', 'Eur 10', 'Eur1.10', 'Eur1,99', 'Eur10', '1.10 dollar', '1,99 dollar', '10 dollar']
```

---

> If you wish to explore/simplify/modify the expression, it's been
> explained on the top right panel of
> [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/uy3NNZ/1). If you'd like, you
> can also watch in [this
> link](https://regex101.com/r/uy3NNZ/1/debugger), how it would match
> against some sample inputs.

---

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Comment: You could add the flag [re.IGNORECASE](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.IGNORECASE) for case-insensitive matching.

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I'm looking for